# How will a back dated transaction insert be traced in a timeseries container in griddb?

Tags: audit, accounting, griddb, banking, computer-forensics

Is the insertion of a past transaction in an accounting database on a timeseries container traceable for audit purpose? How will the timeseries container treat such a back-dated transaction in say banking or accounting data? Can we use such audit trail for forensic purpose?

It is an issue I face in a banking application I developed using other databases, where audit trail could be compromised with help from complicit IT resource(s). So, I am considering the use of GridDB.